# The Chance of Your Team vs. Another Team Having AFK

Tags: probability

My friends and I enjoy League of Legends, a Multi-Only Battle Arena game. It's lots of fun, except for one problem - there are commonly people who leave the game (rage quit, Away From Keyboard (AFK), don't ever connect).

My friend, one night, was complaining about the amount of AFKers we seem to have, and I brought up the fact that, statistically speaking, we have far less of a chance to have the AFK than the other team. My reasoning behind my statement was this:

My group of friends consists of 4 people (out of a total 5 man team comp per team). As such, I know 4/5 people will not be an AFKer. The other team is an unknown. Out of the 5/5 people, there is a higher chance that at least one will be an AFKer compared to my team. Over time, the odds should be in our favor (assuming all other statistics are the same as far as skill level, etc.).

Unfortunately, I am unable to explain why this is true (if it indeed is - I seem to remember that this would be true...but I can't remember where I may have learned that). Would appreciate any explanation here.

Comment: Maybe I should find people to play with... the solo queue is infested with AFKs.

Comment: Why the -1 vote? Would love an explanation...I can fix my question if it's bad.

Comment: AFK means away from keyboard, right?

Comment: @SujaanKunalan - Ah...yes. Let me fix that. Thanks.

Comment: If you want a mathematical formula, you'd need to posit a probability $0<p<1$ that a random person (not you or your friends) is AFK, and then perhaps the probability that a team with $j$ non-AFK people beats a team with $k$ non-AFK people for $0\le j,k\le 5$. But that seems overkill - in this situation, it seems intuitively clear that a team with $4$ known non-AFK has an advantage. - Put another way: I'm not sure exactly what question you're asking.

Comment: @GregMartin - I can see why it seems like a non-question. The question my friend asked was, "That doesn't seem right. We don't get AFKs 20% of the time." I knew I wasn't explaining it right (even though it seems intuitive). I was trying to figure out how to explain the above. Maybe this is a bad question...